# What's the difference between --option and nargs='?' in Python's argparse module?

Tags: python, arguments, argparse, optional-arguments

Having read the documentation on argparse I am struggling to see the difference between the last two lines of code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--option')
parser.add_argument('option', nargs='?')
```

Both specify optional parameters that can be passed into the parser, but why use one over the other?

Comment: Use the positional version if you want to save typing, and the flagged version if you want a more robust input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any argument that starts with `-` and `--` can be used in any order (like `**kwargs`) whereas an argument without the dash prefix is known as a positional argument (like `*args`).

Positional arguments must be provided in the order in which they are defined. A good example of using `nargs='?'`, is to provide a method of redirecting the results of your script to a file. You specify the final argument to be an optional destination file, if the option is not provided the output is simply written to *stdout*.

From a convention point of view, you can consider prefixed arguments as optional flags whereas positional arguments are required.